# Actionscript Menu trouble

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I am very new to Action script. I am trying to make a game which has new game/save/load functions and I am coming across a lot of problems can somebody please help me?

I will explain things from the top, so far I created a place with 3 slots each with input text saying `New Game` and delete button besides it.

What I want is to be able to change the name of this text field only once and then the program saves it.

I also want a delete option with it too. That when you press the delete button it deletes the cookie file the text field is associated with and it resets the name to new game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the game saves? In that action you can change the contents of the input and set it do disabled, or simply replace it with a label that displays the name of that game.

You need to add click handler to the delete buttons, so you can react on the user pressing the button. You delete the file and then resets the input text/replaces the label with an input.